# Creating supabase client with Basic Auth

Tags: supabase, next.js13, supabase-database, supabase-js

I need to interact with my supabase database from a Nextjs webhook route handler that is invoked by an external system. This is not from the browser so there is no user session or cookies available. The external system makes the webhook call using credentials that I have provided them and the credentials are passed in a `basic authorization` header. I tried using that header to create a supabase client but its not working. I am unable to obtain a session or user object after creating this client.

It seems like I need a Bearer token based authorization header (instead of basic authorization header) but there is no logged in user in this case to get the access token from. How can I log in a user for a webhook call, even if I have credentials (user/pass) for that webhook user?

Here is the code to create the supabase client:

```
const supabaseClient = createClient(
            process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
            process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
            {
                auth: {
                    persistSession: false,
                },
                global: {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: req.headers.get('authorization'),
                    },
                },
            }
        );
```

I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you would have username and password, you could always create the client in a normal way (without any authorization headers) and make a [signIn](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signinwithpassword) call first on the client:

```
supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({ email: email, password: password })
```

Then you could process your webhook in the user context and at the end could do a `supabase.auth.signOut()`.

With this you should probably always use a new created supabase client in each request to avoid processing with the wrong context.